# Implementing binary heap in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap

I wanted to implement Max-Heap data structure in C++. It has to be dynamically allocated to take as little memory as possible. I wrote two functions for it, Push, and Heapify (basing on Cormen's Introduction to algorithms), but for input 1,3,5,7 I get heap that looks like 5;1;3;7 (so 7 is left son of one) and I cannot find where I made a mistake.

```
int parent(int i) { return (i - 1) / 2; }
int left(int i) { return 2 * i + 1; }
int right(int i) { return 2 * i + 2; }

// Inserting element into heap
void Push(int val) {

    int *tmp = new int[size + 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < size; i++) tmp[i] = arr[i];
    tmp[size] = val; // Insert as leaf
    delete[] arr;
    arr = new int[size + 1];
    arr = tmp;
    size++;
    Heapify(arr, 0);
}

void Heapify(int *arr, int i) {

    int largest, tmp;
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    if ((l <= size) && (arr[l] > arr[i])) largest = l;
    else largest = i;
    if ((r <= size) && (arr[r] > arr[largest])) largest = r;
    if (largest != i) {
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[largest];
        arr[largest] = tmp;
        Heapify(arr, largest);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Those are methods in Heap class

Comment: You should try to solve your problem with a debugger first and post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still can't figure out what is wrong. This is not a free debugging service. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: I was going to post a basic main with the Push and Heapify calls you indicate (and chide you for not posting a mcve), but you have errors everywhere. You haven't put in enough effort to claim to be stuck on a specific problem. I can help you out by suggesting std::vector for your internal storage (arr). Try using the "at" method instead of [] until you at least fix the out of range errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code and algorithm:

### Problems of your algorithm

The role of `Heapify` method is maintaining the heap property for a node, in which the left and right subtrees are already max-heaps, and only the node itself may violate the heap property. You are using it incorrectly to insert a key into the heap. You need to use `IncreaseKey` to insert a new key into the heap:

```
void IncreaseKey(int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = value;
    int parentIndex;
    while(index > 0 && arr[(parentIndex = parent(index))] < arr[index]){
        int tmp = arr[parentIndex];
        arr[parentIndex] = arr[index];
        arr[index] = tmp;
        index = parentIndex;
    }
}
```

and the `Push` method becomes:

```
void Push(int val) {
    int *tmp = new int[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tmp[i] = arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
    arr = tmp;
    size++;
    IncreaseKey(size-1, val);
}
```

### Problems of your code

In `Heapify` method, you have these conditions:

```
if ((l <= size) && ...
```

and

```
if ((r <= size) && ...
```

`<=` should be changed to `<`, because you already increased `size` before calling `Heapify`.

There are also other problems in your code:

- It is better to change this:

  ```
  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < size; i++) tmp[i] = arr[i];
  ```

  to this (#1):

  ```
  for (int i; i < size; i++) tmp[i] = arr[i];
  ```

  or this (but the code above is still better, because it limits the scope of `i` to `for` statement) (#2):

  ```
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < size; i++) tmp[i] = arr[i];
  ```

  There is no functional difference between them, but first part of you `for` loop does nothing, and also you don't need `i` after the loop. So #1 is the best.
- There is a more subtle problem in these lines:

  ```
  arr = new int[size + 1];
  arr = tmp;
  ```

  You allocated a memory, and without freeing it, reassigned the variable, and lost the address of allocated memory. `tmp` is already assigned to your allocated memory, so remove the first line, and you're good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're right in all your points, but none of them unfortunatelly helps me with my problem.